# Use ionic for a mobile website

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have developed a mobile website with ionic. 
It works very well except when loading ionic.css and ionic.bundle.min.js.

ionic.min.css is about 177k and ionic.bundle.min.js is about 415k
Their sizes are too big for a simple mobile website, and make the site load slowly.

Is there any other angular framework specially for mobile website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is, [Angular Mobile Demo](http://mobileangularui.com/demo)

Here is the [Home Page](http://mobileangularui.com/)

Comment: TNX for your answer. This framework seems not sustained now. But I can not find other framework. :(